# What is the purpose of List<Void>?

Tags: java, list, generics, void

I didn't even know this was doable, but I saw while perusing some code online a method with a signature like this:

```
public List<Void> read( ... )
```

... What?  Is there ever a reason to do this?  What could this `List` even hold?  As far as I was aware, it's not possible to instantiate a `Void` object.

Comment: Didn't the place where you saw the code explains it? I can't find any purpose for it right now.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html

Comment: I used to use it in [`SwingWorker<T,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [`AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11968789/894284) for the Haskell version recently.  Basically, a type inhabited by 0 values can be used to provide more guarantees through a static type system.  However, `null` kind of defeats this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is possible that this method signature was created as a by-product of some generic class.

For example, `SwingWorker` has two type parameters, one for final result and one for intermediate results. If you just don't want to use any intermediate results, you pass `Void` as the type parameter, resulting in some methods returning `Void` - i.e. nothing.

If there were a method `List<V> returnAllIntermediateResults()` in `SwingWorker` with `Void` as the type parameter `V`, it would have created a method just like you posted in your question.

The code would be perfectly valid. You can instantiate any implementation of the `List` interface (e.g. `ArrayList`) with type parameter `Void`. But the only value a `Void` type can have is `null`. So the list could not hold anything else but `null`s, if the implementation allows `null` elements.

Comment: I see.  Very interesting!  This is likely what I saw.  Talk about crazy by products.

Comment: Good answer, but you can technically create an instance of Void through reflection. I have no idea why you'd ever want to do that though.

Comment: @Jeff I don't like Void type very much. Usually when I see it, it means some advanced incomprehensible type wizardry is going on. The only 'reasoneable' use I saw was with the SwingWorker.

Comment: The `Void` type is often used for callback mechanisms accepting generic types and one of them being the return type. This can be `Void` if the function or callback returns nothing. For example, Android's `AsyncTask` accepts as third generic parameter the type of the `Result`. This could theoretically be anything, because it is not used anyways, but the type `Void` is often used to make its purpose clear.

Answer (score 12):

One case in which it may be useful is if you wanted to return a collection of return values from a function. Say

```
static List<T> forEach(Func<A,T> func, List<A> items) {
   List<T> ret = new List<T>();
   for(int i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
     ret.add(func.call(items[i]);
   }
   return ret;
}

public static void main() {
  ...
  List<Void> boringResult = 
   forEach(
    new Func<Void, Integer> {@override Void call(Integer i) {...}});
}
```

Not that useful but you could see a case where it was required.

Comment: Huh.  Talk about a fringe case.  Thanks for your answer!  Very interesting.

Comment: Add `java.concurrent.Future` and `Callable` to the list. There a `Void` return type is not uncommon.

Comment: The only possible return value from `Void call(Integer i) {...}` is `null`, since (according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)): _"The Void class is an **uninstantiable** placeholder class"_ (emphasis added). I'm not sure how useful it is to construct a list that can only contain `null` references.

Comment: @TedHopp - Agreed, but if you are using a generic function such as the forEach above it may be easier to support that then disallow or create another overload.

Answer (score 9):

`List<Void>` is weird. It can only have `null` elements, since you can't create an object of type `Void`. I don't think there is a practical use for such a thing.

`Void` is part of `java.lang`. It's not a special keyword or anything. It's a "pseudo-type" (according to the docs) used to as a place-holder to represent the `Class` object corresponding to `void`, as in `Class<Void>`. From [the docs for `Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> The primitive Java types (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`), and the keyword `void` are also represented as `Class` objects.

The `Void` class exists mainly for the sake of the last part of this, so you can write:

```
Class<Void> voidType = void.class; // == Void.TYPE
```

just like you can write:

```
Class<Integer> intType = int.class; // == Integer.TYPE
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree, it's odd.

I can see a use for it if you want to extend a generic class and return void from a method.  I've bumped into a case were I want to use `int` and had to use `Integer` because java generics don't like primitive types.

```
public interface ObjectUserPool<E, T> {
    public E useObject(T o);
}

public class NonReturningObjectUserPool extends ObjectUserPool<Void, Integer> {
    public Void useObject(Integer i);
}
```

I think this is what the java API is saying, though to be honest I can't really find a use for `NonReturningObjectUserPool`.

Comment: You can return `null` for any reference type; it doesn't require anything special like `Void`.

Comment: @TedHopp good point, answer edited.  I think it's still valid to want to return void to be self documenting; rather than claiming to return Integer and then internally always returning null, and claiming in javadoc that you always return null or something.