# Can I constrain a type family?

Tags: haskell

In [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132830/828361), I happened to crack open this old chestnut (a program so old, half of it was written in the seventeenth century by Leibniz and written on a computer in the seventies by my dad). I'll leave out the modern bit to save space.

```
class Differentiable f where
  type D f :: * -> *

newtype K a     x  = K a
newtype I       x  = I x
data (f :+: g)  x  = L (f x)
                   | R (g x)
data (f :*: g)  x  = f x :&: g x

instance Differentiable (K a) where
  type D (K a) = K Void
instance Differentiable I where
  type D I = K ()
instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :+: g) where
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :*: g) where
  type D (f :*: g) = (D f :*: g) :+: (f :*: D g)
```

Now, here's the frustrating thing. I don't know how to stipulate that `D f` must *itself* be differentiable. Certainly, these instances respect that property, and there might well be fun programs you can write which make use of the ability to keep differentiating a functor, shooting holes in more and more places: Taylor expansions, that sort of thing.

I'd like to be able to say something like

```
class Differentiable f where
  type D f
  instance Differentiable (D f)
```

and require a check that instance declarations have `type` definitions for which the necessary instances exist.

Maybe more mundane stuff like

```
class SortContainer c where
  type WhatsIn c
  instance Ord (WhatsIn c)
  ...
```

would also be nice. That, of course, has the fundep workaround

```
class Ord w => SortContainer c w | c -> w where ...
```

but to attempt the same trick for `Differentiable` seems... well... involuted.

So, is there a nifty workaround that gets me repeatable differentiability? (I guess I could build a representation GADT and and and... but is there a way that works with classes?)

And are there any obvious snags with the suggestion that we should be able to demand constraints on type (and, I suppose, data) families when we declare them, then check that the instances satisfy them?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Can't you just specify the constraint at the call site?  Also, is there any reason that `D f` must be repeatedly differentiable like this?  It's not a requirement of derivatives (in the mathematical sense) in general, and I don't see why it's a precondition for a valid derivative in this particular setting either.

Comment: I want to characterize infinite differentiability, so I can write programs which might make arbitrarily many holes in data. In classical real analysis, there are functions with wonky corners which are not infinitely differentiable, but it's not obvious how to build these things with parametric types. But you're right that there's no reason to assume that differentiable things are infinitely differentiable. Infinite differentiability is still a desirable thing to capture.

Comment: @JohnL: In a sense, it's not logically a *constraint* here--any type constructed from products, sums, `()`, `Void`, `I`, and `K` in this fashion corresponds to a polynomial, and will be infinitely differentiable for the same reasons those are--you'll eventually get `K Void` or something equivalent, which is a fixed point of the derivative. The quandary here is not about requiring an additional property, it's about telling GHC that a particular property will always hold for all valid instances.

Comment: I could, of course, add more instances, e.g. D [] = [] :*: [], which would ensure that repeated differentiation would not always result in something isomorphic to K Void. For composition, add D (f :.: g) = (D f :.: g) :*: D g. For free monads add D (Free f) = ([] :.: D f :.: (Free f)). We can certainly stay smooth without needing to be nilpotent.

Answer (score 48):

Certainly, the obvious thing would be to simply write the desired constraint directly:

```
class (Differentiable (D f)) => Differentiable (f :: * -> *) where
```

Alas, GHC gets huffy about that and refuses to play along:

```
ConstrainTF.hs:17:1:
    Cycle in class declaration (via superclasses):
      Differentiable -> Differentiable
    In the class declaration for `Differentiable'
```

So, as is often the case when attempting to describe type constraints fancy enough to leave GHC recalcitrant, we must resort to some manner of underhanded trickery.

Recalling some relevant features of GHC where type hackery is involved:

- It is paranoid about type-level nontermination far out of proportion to the actual inconvenience it entails for the user.
- It will cheerfully commit itself to decisions about classes and instances before it has considered all the information available.
- It will dutifully attempt to check anything you've tricked it into committing to.

These are the devious principles underlying the familiar old faux-generic instances, where types are unified post-hoc with `(~)` in order to improve the type inference behavior of certain type hackery constructs.

In this case, however, rather than sneaking *type* information past GHC, we would need to somehow prevent GHC from noticing a *class constraint*, which is an *entirely different kind* of... heeeey, waaaitaminute....

```
import GHC.Prim

type family DiffConstraint (f :: * -> *) :: Constraint
type instance DiffConstraint f = Differentiable f

class (DiffConstraint (D f)) => Differentiable (f :: * -> *) where
  type D f :: * -> *
```

Hoist by its own petard!

It's the real deal, too. These are accepted, as you'd hope:

```
instance Differentiable (K a) where
  type D (K a) = K Void
instance Differentiable I where
  type D I = K ()
```

But if we offer it some nonsense instead:

```
instance Differentiable I where
  type D I = []
```

GHC presents us with precisely the error message we'd like to see:

```
ConstrainTF.hs:29:10:
    No instance for (Differentiable [])
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Differentiable [])
    In the instance declaration for `Differentiable I'
```

There is one small snag, of course, namely that this:

```
instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :+: g) where
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
```

...turns out to be less than well-founded, as we've told GHC to check that, whenever `(f :+: g)` is `Differentiable`, so is `(D f :+: D g)`, which does not end well (or at all).

The easiest way to avoid this would usually be to boilerplate on a pile of explicit base cases, but here GHC seems intent on diverging any time a `Differentiable` constraint appears in an instance context. I would assume it's being unnecessarily eager in checking instance constraints somehow, and could perhaps be distracted long enough with another layer of trickery, but I'm not immediately sure where to start and have exhausted my capacity for post-midnight type hackery tonight.

---

A bit of IRC discussion on #haskell managed to jog my memory slightly on how GHC handles class context constraints, and it appears we can patch things up a little bit by means of a pickier constraint family. Using this:

```
type family DiffConstraint (f :: * -> *) :: Constraint
type instance DiffConstraint (K a) = Differentiable (K a)
type instance DiffConstraint I = Differentiable I
type instance DiffConstraint (f :+: g) = (Differentiable f, Differentiable g)
```

We now have a much more well-behaved recursion for sums:

```
instance (Differentiable (D f), Differentiable (D g)) => Differentiable (f :+: g) where
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
```

The recursive case cannot be so easily bisected for products, however, and applying the same changes there improved matters only insofar as I received a context reduction stack overflow rather than it simply hanging in an infinite loop.

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you (and your friends on #haskell) for this investigation. I realise I'm trying to persuade a computer to do some sort of proof by induction... but yes it is rather fun trying to see which constraint problems it will fall for.

Comment: @pigworker: The irritating thing here is that the induction involved is clearly within GHC's capability to understand, but the usual approach of brazenly asserting an inductive step knowing that GHC will be able to figure things out at the call site fails because class constraints must be satisfied at the instance. In a way, this forces us to actually prove the inductive step itself, rather than treating it as advice to GHC on how to prove arbitrary specific cases on its own. Should be possible, with enough hand-holding to walk GHC through it.

Answer (score 19):

Your best bet might be to define something using the `constraints` package:

```
import Data.Constraint

class Differentiable (f :: * -> *) where
  type D f :: * -> *
  witness :: p f -> Dict (Differentiable (D f))
```

then you can manually open the dictionary whenever you need to recurse.

This would let you employ the general shape of the solution in Casey's answer, but not have the compiler (or runtime) spin forever on induction.

Comment: Having spent additional time tinkering with my code trying for a more direct approach, I'm inclined to say that this is the way to go. The best I managed was getting it to hang when trying to use the instances instead of merely define them.

Comment: How would you implement `witness` or recover a method using `witness`?

Comment: Interestingly, for all types `witness = Dict` more or less. The idea is that the `Dict` constructor will capture the `Differentiable (D f)` from the definition context. Then, later, when you pattern match on `Dict` (which is silly from a value-level POV) GHC will suddenly "remember" whatever instance the `Dict` captured from before. It's all sort of obvious-System-F-magical-Haskell wonkery. It may be the case that at definition time declaring `Dict` isn't sufficient since GHC can't figure out `Differentiable (D f)`, so then the rest of `constraints` gives you mechanisms to help GHC's inference

Answer (score 13):

With the new `UndecidableSuperclasses` in GHC 8

```
class Differentiable (D f) => Differentiable (f :: Type -> Type) where
```

works.

Answer (score 9):

This can be accomplished in the same manner as Edward suggests with a tiny implementation of `Dict`. First, let's get the language extensions and imports out of the way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Proxy
```

`TypeOperators` is only for your example problem.

#### Tiny Dict

We can make our own tiny implementation of `Dict`. `Dict` uses a GADT and `ConstraintKinds` to capture any constraint in the constructor for a GADT.

```
data Dict c where
    Dict :: c => Dict c
```

`withDict` and `withDict2` reintroduce the constraint by pattern matching on the GADT. We only need to be able to reason about terms with one or two sources of constraints.

```
withDict :: Dict c -> (c => x) -> x
withDict Dict x = x

withDict2 :: Dict a -> Dict b -> ((a, b) => x) -> x
withDict2 Dict Dict x = x
```

#### Infinitely differentiable types

Now we can talk about infinitely differentiable types, whose derivatives must also be differentiable

```
class Differentiable f where
    type D f :: * -> *
    d2 :: p f -> Dict (Differentiable (D f))
    -- This is just something to recover from the dictionary
    make :: a -> f a
```

`d2` takes a proxy for the type, and recovers the dictionary for taking the second derivative. The proxy allows us to easily specify which type's `d2` we are talking about. We can get to deeper dictionaries by applying `d`:

```
d :: Dict (Differentiable t) -> Dict (Differentiable (D t))
d d1 = withDict d1 (d2 (pt (d1)))
    where
        pt :: Dict (Differentiable t) -> Proxy t
        pt = const Proxy
```

#### Capturing the dictonary

The polynomial functor types, products, sums, constants, and zero, are all infinitely differentiable. We will define the `d2` witnesses for each of these types

```
data    K       x  = K              deriving (Show)
newtype I       x  = I x            deriving (Show)
data (f :+: g)  x  = L (f x)
                   | R (g x)
                                    deriving (Show)
data (f :*: g)  x  = f x :&: g x    deriving (Show)
```

Zero and constants don't require any additional knowledge to capture their derivative's `Dict`

```
instance Differentiable K where
  type D K = K
  make = const K
  d2 = const Dict

instance Differentiable I where
  type D I = K
  make = I
  d2 = const Dict
```

Sum and product both require the dictionaries from both of their component's derivatives to be able to deduce the dictionary for their derivative.

```
instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :+: g) where
  type D (f :+: g) = D f :+: D g
  make = R . make
  d2 p = withDict2 df dg $ Dict
    where
        df = d2 . pf $ p
        dg = d2 . pg $ p
        pf :: p (f :+: g) -> Proxy f
        pf = const Proxy
        pg :: p (f :+: g) -> Proxy g
        pg = const Proxy

instance (Differentiable f, Differentiable g) => Differentiable (f :*: g) where
  type D (f :*: g) = (D f :*: g) :+: (f :*: D g)
  make x = make x :&: make x
  d2 p = withDict2 df dg $ Dict
    where
        df = d2 . pf $ p
        dg = d2 . pg $ p
        pf :: p (f :*: g) -> Proxy f
        pf = const Proxy
        pg :: p (f :*: g) -> Proxy g
        pg = const Proxy
```

#### Recovering the dictionary

We can recover the dictionary for constraints that we otherwise wouldn't have adequate information to deduce. `Differentiable f` would normally only let use get to `make :: a -> f a`, but not to either `make :: a -> D f a` or `make :: a -> D (D f) a`.

```
make1 :: Differentiable f => p f -> a -> D f a
make1 p = withDict (d2 p) make

make2 :: Differentiable f => p f -> a -> D (D f) a
make2 p = withDict (d (d2 p)) make
```