# Is complex differentiation of datatypes sensible?

Tags: haskell, types, calculus

pigworker once asked [how to express that a type is infinitely differentiable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14133121). This question brought to mind the fact that in complex analysis, a function that is differentiable (on an open set) must be infinitely differentiable (on that set). Is there a way to talk about complex differentiation of datatypes? If so, does a similar theorem hold?

Comment: are you sure this is a SO question and not [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) or similar?

Comment: @ErikAllik, CSTheory seems to be exclusively for grad students and researchers. CS seems barely populated. Such questions often get answers from the Haskell crowd here.

Comment: luckily it's one of those things non-haskellers won't understand and thus won't close, and haskellers just won't close anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Not really an answer... but this rant is way too long for a comment*.

I find it a bit misleading to think complex differentiability just implies infinite differentiability. It's in fact much stronger than that: if a function is complex differentiable, then its derivatives at any point [determine the entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem). And because infinite differentiability gives you a full Taylor series, you have an analytic function which is equal to your function, i.e. is your function itself. So, in a sense complex differentiable functions are analytic... because they are.

<sub>From a (standard) calculus perspective, the key contrast between real diff'ability and complex diff'ability is that in the reals, there is only one direction in which you can take the limit of difference-quotients (*f*(*x*+*δ*) - *f x*)/*δ*. You merely require that the left limit equals the right limit. But because that's an equality *after* the limit, this has only an effect locally. (Topologically speaking, the constraint just compares two discrete values, so it doesn't really deal with continuity properties at all.)</sub>
<sub>OTOH, for complex differentiability we require that the limit of the difference quotient is the same if we approach *x* from any direction in the entire complex plane. That's an entire continuous degree of freedom constrained. You can then go on to perform topological tricks (Cauchy integrals are essentially that) to “spread” the constraint through the entire domain.</sub>

I consider this a bit problematic philosophically. **Holomorphic functions aren't really functions at all**, as in: they're not so much defined by the entirety of their result values across the domain, as by some way to write them with analytic formulas (i.e. possibly-infinite algebraic expressions / polynomials).

<sub>Most mathematicians and physicists apparently like this a lot – such expressions are just the way in which they generally write functions.

I don't, really, like it at all: to me, a function should be a function, something defined by individual values, like field strengths you can measure in space or results you can define in Haskell.

Anyway, I digress...</sub>

If we translate this issue from functions on numbers to functors on Haskell types, I suppose the upshot is that complex diff'ability means nothing else but: a type *can be written as a (possibly infinite?) ADT polynomial*. And how to get infinite differentiability for such ADTs was shown in [the post you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14133121).

---

### Another spin... perhaps closer to an answer.

These “derivatives” of Haskell types aren't really derivatives in the calculus sense. As in, they aren't motivated by a concept of small-pertubation response analysis<sup>†</sup>. It so happens that you can mathematically proove, for a very specific class of functions – those defined by an algebraic expression – that the calculus-derivative can again be written in a simple algebraic way (given by the well-known differentiation rules). That means trivially that you can differentiate infinitely often.

The usefulness of this symbolic differentiation also motivates to think about it as a more abstract operation. And when you're differentiating Haskell types, it is mainly just this algebraic definition you're going after, not the original calculus one.

Which is fine... but once you're doing algebra rather than calculus, it's not very meaningful to distinguish “real” from “complex” – it's actually neither, because you're *not* handling values but symbolic representations of values. An untyped language, if you will (and indeed, Haskell's type language is still untyped, with everything having kind `*`).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Be it with traditional convergent limits or [NSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis)-infinitesimals.</sub>

Comment: So if you close off the universe to admit only the possible forms of holomorphic functions, you get infinite differentiability "for free"?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't quite understand what you mean by that. I added another way to look at it in the answer.