# Transitive 'Subset` class for type-level-sets

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, higher-kinded-types, type-kinds, undecidable-instances

I'm working with Dominic Orchard's [type-level-sets](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-sets-0.8.9.0) library, which follows [his paper](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dao7/publ/haskell14-effects.pdf) pretty closely.

I'm building a DSL for expressing communication between parties during a synchronous concurrent program. One thing I'm going to need is the ability to express "sub-programs" involving sub-sets of the original community; this will be used in conjunction with `fromUniversal`.

Here's a parred down version of my code:

```hs
module Lib () where

import Data.Type.Nat (Nat)
import Data.Type.Set (IsSet, Subset)
import Polysemy (Sem, makeSem, reinterpret)

data Located (parties :: [Nat]) v = Located v

data Com (parties :: [Nat]) m a where
  SendInt :: forall recipients senders parties m.
             (Subset recipients parties,
              Subset senders parties) =>
             Located senders Int -> Com parties m (Located recipients Int)
  FromUniversal :: forall parties m a.
               Located parties a -> Com parties m a

-- Polysemy uses template haskell:
makeSem ''Com
--sendInt :: Member...=> (Located senders Int) -> Sem r (Located recipients Int)
--fromUniversal :: Member (Com parties) r => (Located parties a) -> Sem r a
--We can manually write them out instead of using makeSem;
--that helps make Located's type argument explicit.

-- Lift a program in a small community (clique) into a larger community's monad. 
runClique :: forall parties clq s r a.
          (IsSet parties,
           IsSet clq,
           Subset clq parties) =>
          Sem (Com clq ': r) a -> Sem (Com parties ': r) (Located clq a)
runClique program = do
    a <- (reinterpret _clique) program
    return (Located a)
  where _clique :: forall rInitial x.
                   Com clq (Sem rInitial) x -> Sem (Com parties ': r) x
        _clique (SendInt l) = sendInt l
```

Within `_clique`, there are contexts providing `Subset recipients clq` and `Subset csl parties`; I need GHC to somehow understand that this implies `Subset recipients parties`. But there's no such instance available.

**How can I represent the transitivity of "subset" for the purposes of type-level sets?**

Here's the error message:

```
~/.../src/Lib.hs:35:31: error:
    • Could not deduce (Subset recipients parties)
        arising from a use of ‘sendInt’
      from the context: (IsSet parties, IsSet clq, Subset clq parties)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   runClique :: forall k (parties :: [Nat]) (clq :: [Nat]) (s :: k)
                                       (r :: [(* -> *) -> * -> *]) a.
                                (IsSet parties, IsSet clq, Subset clq parties) =>
                                Sem (Com clq : r) a -> Sem (Com parties : r) (Located clq a)
        at src/Lib.hs:(25,1)-(29,72)
      or from: (x ~ Located recipients Int, Subset recipients clq,
                Subset senders clq)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   SendInt :: forall k (recipients :: [Nat]) (senders :: [Nat])
                                     (parties :: [Nat]) (m :: k).
                              (Subset recipients parties, Subset senders parties) =>
                              Located senders Int -> Com parties m (Located recipients Int),
                 in an equation for ‘_clique’
        at src/Lib.hs:35:18-26
    • In the expression: sendInt l
      In an equation for ‘_clique’: _clique (SendInt l) = sendInt l
      In an equation for ‘runClique’:
          runClique program
            = do a <- (reinterpret _clique) program
                 return (Located a)
            where
                _clique ::
                  forall rInitial x.
                  Com clq (Sem rInitial) x -> Sem (Com parties : r) x
                _clique (SendInt l) = sendInt l
   |
35 |         _clique (SendInt l) = sendInt l
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried simply adding

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (Subset s t, Subset t v) => Subset s v where
  subset xs = subset (subset xs :: Set t)
```

to Lib.hs (apparently `Subset` isn't closed-world; I *think*); this gives a variety of different error messages depending what compiler options I use, or if I swap out `OVERLAPS` for `INCOHERENT`. The jist of it seems to be that GHC can't pick an instance to use, even if I promise it'll be ok.

I tried making the `recipient` type explicit in `_clique` (so I can just add the needed `Subset recipients parties` to the context), but it seems like no matter what I do `reinterpret` always introduces/requires a "fresh" `x` and/or `recipients`; I haven't found a way of providing the context for the type-variable that's actually used.

It seems unlikely that this is impossible, but I've been stuck on it for a day and I'm out of my depth.

##### Edit

I've been proceeding with the project using the below solution; it's distinctly mediocre. Specifically, there are a lot of properties *besides* just transitivity that would be nice to have, like two sets are both subsets of a third set, then their union is a also a subset of the third set. Getting properties like that "for free" may be too much to ask of Haskell's type system...

Comment: I don't see any code at the reddit post, for what it's worth. To me it looks like a completely blank post, just the title and no other contents.

Comment: As for your question: I expect you will probably need to define `transitive :: (Subset s t, Subset t v) => Set s -> Set v` and apply it manually at appropriate moments. Does this work for you? If not, can you edit your question to talk a bit about why not? Another possibility would be `class Middleman t where proof :: (Subset s t, Subset t v) => Dict (Subset s v)` with instances for the empty type-level list and for non-empty type-level list, though I'm less confident that this is possible to implement.

Comment: @DanielWagner; It's unclear how `transitive` would help; at no point am I trying to get a `Set v` from a `Set s`. Did you mean `Subset s t, Subset t v) => Set v -> Set s` (as `instance (...) Subset s v` would require)? Actually declaring the instance hasn't helped (so far), and applying the function doesn't make sense as there are no inhabitants of these `Set` types in sight.

Comment: The `Middleman` tactic sounds like it's talking about the strategy described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577827/10135377), but I haven't fully made sense of that post yet, and it's unclear if `Dict` is some existing thing I should be able to find documentation for. Do you have links? Would you want to write out a (not necessarily complete or working) answer?

Comment: Yes, of course `Set v -> Set s`, sorry. I'm not sure what to tell you. You're going to have to change your approach. I'd love to help you with that, but at the moment it's really hard to say anything useful without understanding your goals. If you take us down the garden path -- what is the *top-level* thing you're trying to achieve, and what are all the steps that you think inevitably lead to needing this? -- then we may be able to point out places along the path where you could deviate. Dict is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict).

Comment: I've added a lot more context and code, and removed the reddit link.

Comment: Instead of having `SendInt :: (Subset recipients parties, Subset senders parties)  => ..` you could instead use `SendInt :: SubsetWitness recipients parties -> SubsetWitness senders parties -> ...`  where `SubsetWitness` is a type which witnesses the proof that one set is a subset of another. Then also define your own class `class Subset s t where subsetWitness :: SubsetWitness s t`; you recover the syntax in the OP with `sendInt' = sendInt subsetWitness subsetWitness`.

Comment: @user2407038; That sounds plausible, but it's not clear to me from your description how to get transitivity out of it.

Answer (score 1):

GHC Haskell only really supports transitivity for two types of constraints:

1. (Nominal) equality constraints

   ```
   (a ~ b, b ~ c) => a ~ c
   ```
2. Representational equality constraints

   ```
   (Coercible a b, Coercible b c) => Coercible a c
   ```

These rules are (very carefully) baked into the constraint solving process for the entirely magical `~` and `Coercible` constraints; there is no other transitivity in the constraint language. The basic problem is that if you have a class

```
class C a b
```

and you write

```
instance (C a b, C b c) => C a c
```

then `b` is ambiguous. When GHC is trying to solve `C a c`, it has no idea *what* `b` you want. There is not, at present, any way for the user to indicate which `b` to use where the constraint is demanded, so the instance really can't be used.

The `Subset` type in `Data.Type.Set` does not look like an equality or `Coercible` constraint, so you just can't do it.

Are there other ways to express the idea of a list being a subset of another list that GHC *can* recognize as transitive? I'm not sure. Suppose we had something like

```
class Subset' a b
transitive :: (Subset' a b, Subset' b c) => SomeProof a b -> SomeProof b c -> Dict (Subset' a c)
```

I would be surprised if it were possible to define `transitive` without using its proof arguments. Furthermore, actually *using* such a `Subset'` would likely be difficult, or even impossible.

`Subset'` constraints are likely to look vaguely like one of the following:

```hs
type Subset' a b = Union a b ~ Nub (Sort b)
type Subset' a b = Intersection a b ~ Nub (Sort a)
```

where you may or may not be able to use the provided definitions of `Union`, `Sort`, and `Nub`, and you'd have to come up with your own `Intersection`. I have no doubt whatsoever that any such project will be complicated. You'll have to use the structure of the evidence you're given to construct the necessary equality. And then after all that ... where have you really gotten? This looks like a dead end.

Comment: Thanks! This is disappointing, but I think the conclusion is correct, that Haskell's type system is the wrong tool for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I've been able to come up with is [Ghosts of Departed Proofs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdp-0.0.3.0), which I can use to move the logic of subsets out of the type-system. It's a bit clunky, and I'm not at all sure I'm using it correctly.

##### Subset.hs

```hs
module Subset (
  immediateSubset,
  Subset,
  SubsetProof,
  transitiveSubset,
  unionOfSubsets
) where

import Data.Type.Set (Subset, Union)
import Logic.Classes (Transitive, transitive)
import Logic.Proof (axiom, Proof, sorry)

data Subset' s t where {}
instance Transitive Subset' where {}
type SubsetProof s t = Proof (Subset' s t)

immediateSubset :: (Subset s t) =>
                   SubsetProof s t
immediateSubset = axiom
transitiveSubset :: forall k (s :: [k]) (t :: [k]) (v :: [k]).
                    SubsetProof s t -> SubsetProof t v -> SubsetProof s v
transitiveSubset = transitive
unionOfSubsets :: forall k (s1 :: [k]) (s2 :: [k]) (t :: [k]).
                  SubsetProof s1 t -> SubsetProof s2 t -> SubsetProof (Union s1 s2) t
unionOfSubsets s1t s2t = sorry
```

In this version `unionOfSubsets` isn't being used; in practice it would be nice to have real/better proofs for this and other similar properties.

##### Lib.hs

```hs
module Lib {-()-} where

import Data.Type.Nat (Nat)
import Data.Type.Set (IsSet)
import Polysemy (Sem, makeSem, reinterpret)

import Subset (immediateSubset, Subset, SubsetProof, transitiveSubset)


data Located (parties :: [Nat]) v = Located v

data Com (parties :: [Nat]) m a where
  SendInt :: forall recipients senders parties m.
             SubsetProof recipients parties 
             -> SubsetProof senders parties
             -> Located senders Int
             -> Com parties m (Located recipients Int)
  FromUniversal :: forall parties m a.
                   Located parties a -> Com parties m a

-- Polysemy uses template haskell:
makeSem ''Com
--sendInt :: Member (Com parties) r => (Located senders Int) -> Sem r (Located recipients Int)
--fromUniversal :: Member (Com parties) r => (Located parties a) -> Sem r a
--we can manually write out the functions instead of useing makeSem;
--that might help make Located's type artument explicit, but I don't think it matters here.

-- "lift" a program in a small community (clique) into a larger community's monad. 
runClique :: forall parties clq r a.
          (IsSet parties,
           IsSet clq,
           Subset clq parties) =>
          Sem (Com clq ': r) a
          -> Sem (Com parties ': r) (Located clq a)
runClique = (Located <$>) . (reinterpret _clique)
  where cp = immediateSubset :: SubsetProof clq parties
        _clique :: forall rInitial x.
                   Com clq (Sem rInitial) x -> Sem (Com parties ': r) x
        _clique (SendInt rc sc x) = sendInt (transitiveSubset rc cp) (transitiveSubset sc cp) x
        _clique (FromUniversal (Located v)) = return v
```