# Writing the Identity monad in terms of Free

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

In "Data types a la carte" Swierstra writes that given `Free` (which he calls `Term`) and `Zero` you can implement the Identity monad:

```
data Term f a = Pure a
              | Impure (f (Term f a))
data Zero a
```

`Term Zero` is now the Identity monad. I understand why this is. The issue is that I can never use `Term Zero` as a Monad because of the pesky `Functor f =>` constraint:

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Term f) where
    return x = Pure x
    (Pure x) >>= f = f x 
    (Impure f) >>= t = Impure (fmap (>>=f) t)
```

How do I make `Zero` a Functor?

```
instance Functor Zero where
    fmap f z = ???
```

It seems like there's a trick here: Since `Zero` has no constructors, `Impure` can never be used, and so the `Impure` case of `>>=` is never called. This means `fmap` is never called, so there's a sense in which this is ok:

```
instance Functor Zero where
    fmap f z = undefined
```

The problem is, this feels like cheating. What am I missing? Is `Zero` actually a Functor? Or perhaps `Zero` isn't a Functor, and this is a shortcoming of how we express `Free` in Haskell?

Comment: yes, `Zero` is a functor from `Hask` to `0`, the empty category (which then is embedded back into Hask).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you turn on `DeriveFunctor`, you can write

```
data Zero a deriving Functor
```

but you might consider that cheating. If you want to write it yourself, you can turn on `EmptyCase`, instead, then write the funky-looking

```
instance Functor Zero where
    fmap f z = case z of
```

Comment: I wondered what happens if we cheat and do `fmap f _|_` in both these functor instances. In GHCi 7.10.2, the first instance errors out with `Exception: Void fmap`, without trying to evaluate the bottom, while the second does evaluate it. I'd have expected a non-exhaustiveness error instead. Not that this really matters -- both instances are fine, albeit they produce different bottoms if we pass one.

Comment: @chi You definitely shouldn't expect a non-exhaustiveness error: these pattern matches are exhaustive!

Comment: I somehow expected the practical equivalence between `case e of p1 -> e1 ; .. ; pn -> en` and `case e of ... ; pn -> en ; _ -> error "non exhaustive"`. This "under-the-hood" equivalence only breaks for n=0 (if we do not identify "different" bottoms). About exhaustiveness... I would be more convinced in Agda/Coq or any other total programming language. In Haskell, you are right, but bottoms are strange beasts, and I have no clear idea about whether `case _|_ :: Void of {}` should evaluate the argument or not, operationally speaking.

Answer (score 7):

One way to go about this is to use [`Data.Void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html) instead of an empty `data` declaration, like this:

```
import Data.Void

-- `Zero a` is isomorphic to `Void`
newtype Zero a = Zero Void

instance Functor Zero where
    -- You can promise anything if the precondition is that
    -- somebody's gotta give you an `x :: Void`.
    fmap f (Zero x) = absurd x
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131856/whats-the-absurd-function-in-data-void-useful-for) for some really great explanations of what `Void` is useful for.  But the key idea is that the `absurd :: Void -> a` function lets you go from that can-never-happen `x :: Void` binding into any type you like.

Answer (score 7):

A trick way of defining `Zero a` is the following.

```
newtype Zero a = Zero (Zero a)
```

In other words, it encodes the sort of silly, slightly non-obvious statement that there is actually one way to get a value of `Zero a`: you must already have one!

With this definition, `absurd :: Zero a -> b` is definable in a "natural" way

```
absurd :: Zero a -> b
absurd (Zero z) = absurd z
```

In some sense these definitions are all legal because they point out exactly how they are not possible to instantiate. No values of `Zero a` can be constructed unless someone else "cheats" first.

```
instance Functor Zero where
  fmap f = absurd
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is more or less how the `Data.Void` module is implemented.

Comment: Hah, yes, that is true!

Comment: `Data.Void` used to do this, before `EmptyCase` came out (it was changed when it moved from `void` to `base`). I don't know if it changed for clarity, efficiency, or error reporting reasons. Do you?

Comment: @dfeuer: Oh, I hadn't noticed that `base` now has `Void` (since 4.8.0.0). Note that the old `void` package advertised itself as "a Haskell 98 logically uninhabited data type"; that's the original point of this answer's trick.

Answer (score 3):

Another spin on Luis Casillas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709701/1477667) is to build your type entirely from stock parts:

```
type Id = Free (Const Void)
```

The `Functor` instance for `Const x` will work as you wish (its `fmap` doesn't do anything, which is just fine), and you'll only need to take care when unpacking:

```
runId (Pure x) = x
runId (Free (Const ab)) = absurd ab
```

All of these things, of course, are only "morally" equivalent to `Identity`, because they all introduce extra values. In particular, we can distinguish among

```
bottom
Pure bottom
Free bottom
```