# What is the purpose of algebraic data types without a constructor?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

In Haskell you can define a algebraic data type without a constructor:

```
data Henk
```

But what is the purpose of a type (or kind?) that doesn't have a constructor?

Comment: these are called phantom types; they are useful for parametrizing other types, i.e. passing as type parameter to type constructors, none of whose value constructors expect a value parameter of that phantom type.

Comment: Never mind phantom types (so it's not a duplicate, Erik), there's plenty of sensible motivation for at least one *empty* type: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131856/828361

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type-level machinery often requires types to exist but never constructs values of such types.

E.g., phantom types:

```
module Example (Unchecked, Checked, Stuff()) where

data Unchecked
data Checked
data Stuff c = S Int String Double

check :: Stuff Unchecked -> Maybe (Stuff Checked)
check (S i s d) = if i>43 && ...
                  then Just (S i s d)
                  else Nothing

readFile :: Filepath -> IO (Stuff Unchecked)
readFile f = ...

workWithChecked :: Stuff Checked -> Int -> String
workWithChecked stuff i = ...

workWithAny :: Stuff any -> Int -> Stuff any
workWithAny stuff i = ...
```

As long as the `S` constructor is not exported by the module, the user of this library can not forge the "checked" status on the `Stuff` data type.

Above, the `workWithChecked` function does not have to sanitize the input every time it is called. The user must have already done it, since it has to provide a value in the "checked" type -- and this means the user had to call the `check` function beforehand. This is an efficient and robust design: we do not repeat the same check over and over at every call, and yet we do not allow the user to pass unchecked data.

Note how the values of types `Checked`,`Unchecked` are immaterial -- we never use those.

As others mentioned in comments, there are many other uses of empty types than phantom types. For instance, some GADTs involve empty types. E.g.

```
data Z
data S n
data Vec n a where
  Nil  :: Vec Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

Above we use empty types to record length information in types.

Further, types with no constructors are needed to achieve some theoretical properties: if we look for an `a` such that `Either a T` is isomorphic to `T`, we want `a` to be empty. In type theory, an empty type is commonly used as a type equivalent of a logically "false" proposition.

Comment: That's only part of why phantom types are useful. To extend your example: you could also have a few functions that worked fine on either checked or unchecked `Stuff`, and other functions that only worked on the checked version.

Comment: @JeremyList I totally agree (otherwise, we could simply use two different types instead of a phantom index). I added one more function, to improve a little bit, even the full power of phantom types is not shown here.