# Why does Haskell Pipes "use () to close unused inputs and X (the uninhabited type) to close unused outputs"?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

In the [Pipes Tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.8/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html#g:9), it says that:

> The concrete type synonyms use `()` to close unused inputs and `X` (the
>   uninhabited type) to close unused outputs:

I'd like to understand why `()` and `X` are used the way they are. Why not `X` or `()` for both inputs and outputs?

Comment: You might want to look at this question as well as the excellent answers: ["What's the `absurd` function in `Data.Void` useful for?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131856/whats-the-absurd-function-in-data-void-useful-for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X` in pipes is normally spelled `Void` in the rest of the Haskell ecosystem, so let's pretend `X = Void`. It's defined like this:

```
data Void
```

And it has an "eliminator"

```
absurd :: Void -> a
absurd x = case x of {}
```

If you have something of type `Void` (and force it), then *something has gone wrong*. Your program has produced an error, or it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Making a pipe *produce* things of type `Void` bars it from ever producing anything (legitimate). Making it produce things of type `()` allows it to produce things, but things that carry no information. They're basically clock ticks.

On the input side, a pipe that consumes things of type `Void` can await input, but as soon as it does so it is stuck--no one will be able to feed it anything. A pipe that consumes things of type `()` can await, but only gets clock ticks.

All of these options are reasonable. I suspect Gonzalez wanted the type system to prohibit users from accidentally hooking up a pure producer to a pure consumer the wrong way around, and getting an error that could be hard to track down. By making a pure producer consume `()`, and a pure consumer produce `Void`, he makes it impossible to hook them up the wrong way.

Comment: `Pipes.X` is more like the `Void` of the `void` package, `newtype X = X X`, with `closed (X x) = closed x` for `absurd`, but the point is basically the same.

Comment: @Michael, that's probably because it's an evolutionary remnant that might be too hard to get rid of now. The `Void` package actually only compiles that code for old versions of `base`--otherwise most of the package is gutted by Cabal in favor of the `base` versions.

Comment: So, it would've been just as valid if the library used `data X = X` and `data Y = Y` for input and output since X /= Y and it is also not possible to hook them up ?

Comment: @Ana, I believe all sorts of such things would be valid. Of course, Gonzalez may have some deeper reasoning behind this--he knows a while lot more about category theory and pipes than I do!

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a more general thing than just for pipes. `()` and `X` are the [initial and terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) of the **Hask** category (and of categories derived from **Hask**), meaning that *for all Haskell types `a`*,

- there exists exactly one morphism `a -> ()` (namely `const ()`)
- there exists exactly one morphism `X -> a` (namely `absurd`).

As a consequence, any chain of functions `a -> ()`>>>`() -> b` can't actually depend on the left part (since `a -> ()` carries no information), and any chain `a -> X`>>>`X -> b` can't depend on the right part. In that sense, a `() -> b` input is closed, and so is an `a -> X` output.

Comment: But pipes aren't functions. A pipe can consume without producing, produce without consuming, or even sit around effecting without doing either. I don't think the category of pipes over a non-identity monad is likely to have initial or final objects at all.

Comment: For any two types `a` and `b`, there will be "more" pipes that consume `a` and produce `b` than functions `a -> b`.