# What's the best way of expressing a "never-evaluated" argument to a function in type?

Tags: haskell

Sorry about the title, I don't know if there's a better way to describe it in one short sentence.

The idea is I want a function type to express that the function accepts one argument but will never evaluate it.

There are few alternatives I can think of, and I want to know what would be the best one:

(for all following examples, `Int` is just an arbitrary choice from any concrete types)

1. `f :: forall a . a -> Int`, feeding `f` with anything will do
2. `f :: () -> Int`, there's nothing but a trivial value to be evaluated
3. `f :: Void -> Int`, this could be a bad idea, as it's possible that `f = absurd` and `f` is applied with `undefined` or `let x = x in x`, but if you know `f` terminates, then you also know it will never evaluate its argument.
4. I don't know if there are other ways, please give your suggestions if any.

About why I need a function like this in the first place: suppose I want to design a stream-processing library and let type of stream processors be like `SP <input-type> <output-type>` and it's possible that a processor doesn't need any input. and at some point I'll have to deal with a function like `<input-type> -> <output-type>` if I want to make this an `Arrow`.

Comment: This is probably relevant: [*Why does Haskell Pipes “use () to close unused inputs and X (the uninhabited type) to close unused outputs”?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35161616/2751851)

Comment: @duplode thanks for the link, that's super relevant as I was trying to figure out the reason behind choice of `()` vs. `Void`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is perfect. It will accept an argument of any type, so you have maximum flexibility in what you provide it (even `undefined`). #2 limits you to only a single valid argument, `()`. #3 isn't an option; you can't even *call* the function, because there is no valid argument to give it.

This is exactly what `const :: a -> b -> a` returns. `foo = const 3` is a function that takes a value of any type and returns `3`.