# Practical examples of using Void

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, curry-howard

Edit: By `Void`, I mean Haskell's `Void` type, i.e. empty type that cannot have values but `undefined`.

There is an ongoing discussion on Swift Evolution whether to replace `noreturn` function attribute with an actual `Void` type. To do so, we must be sure that this will bring real benefit to the platform. Using `Void` as return type is just not enough.

So I ask you to provide very *practical* examples, where usage of `Void` adds clarity, brevity, genericity to the code. Maybe it will use classes (in Haskell sense), maybe generics, maybe it will incorporate `Void` in an ADT.

But *please*, don't go too far into HKT, Monads, all that high-level stuff. An utility function from standard library is also a bad example. A perfect example would be part of an arcade game or something like that.

Comment: are you talking about a *unit* type with just one value (mod. undefined) or a real *void* type (no values beside the usual undefined)?

Comment: Void has no inhabitants so how can you return something of type Void.

Comment: @pdexter well many languages uses void as a *special* replacement for a unit-type (C,Java,...)

Comment: @Carsten right, but this question was tagged as Haskell so I assume the author is talking about Haskell's Void.

Comment: I'm confused s well - anyway: I suspect this one will be closed rather quickly - I don't think it's a good fit for SO

Comment: I'm talking about Haskell's Void type. Discussion is whether to replace function's noreturn attribute (for functions like fatalError) with this Void return type. In Swift, it will be called NoReturn or something like this, but in this context it does not really matter. But to do so, - and then read the question.

Comment: @Anton3 can you give an example? Because it just does not make any sense to use *values*  of type `Void` - no matter if you call them `NoReturn` or anything else - a function `a -> Void` in Haskell cannot be meaningful defined

Comment: @Anton3 take a look at how OCaml uses the unit type (`unit`) and its only value (`()`), that would be of better use.

Comment: f# uses exactly this - it translates .net `void` results into `Unit`

Comment: @Carsten If function in Haskell returns Void, then it must return undefined. Then it must crash before returning. So basically, noreturn attribute from C-family is equivlent to returning Void.

Comment: it does not have to *crash* (example `let f :: a -> Void; f x = f x`) - as I said it's a pointless function - totally useless (how is *crashing*  your program the same as having a `void` function in C???)

Comment: @Anton3 sorry, are you claiming that 'returning undefined' in Haskell crashes the program (not necessarily true by itself) and that you want a way to tag functions in Swift which crash the program?

Comment: well I don't think this will get any fitting answer here - I would recommend you visit the haskell IRC or reddit channels instead

Comment: @Carsten I had to add a clarification to the question that by `Void` I *always* mean Haskell's Void, an empty type, and never `void` type from C family.

Comment: anyway if you ask my opinion: if swift wants to be functional then you should either go the `Unit` route or just stick with what you have

Comment: @pdexter Yes, but that use case is not enough, so I want other examples of using `Void`. For examples, `Maybe Void` is equivalent to `()`  (without undefined), but how can that be used? `Either a Void` is equivalent to `a`, but I again can't think of an example where that would really help.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968789/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Speaking of `Void` as the type with *no* values, which is different to the type with just *one* value, usually called Unit.)

In Haskell streaming libraries like [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) or [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), there are data types that represent "a source of values of type `a` that, once exhausted, returns a value of type `r`". Something like `Producer a m r` (The `m` is a base monad but that's not relevant here.)

Having producers return with a value (of a type unrelated to the type of values they emit while running) is actually quite useful. For example, you can define a "streaming splitter" as a function with type:

```
streamingSplit :: Producer a m r -> Producer a m (Producer a m r)
```

This function segments the producer without having to accumulate in memory all the elements preceding the split.

Now, what if we want to express at the type level that a producer *never stops* producing stuff? We can make it return a value of type `Void`, like `Producer a m Void`.

Another possible use-case. Suppose you have a higher-order function that takes a callback that might fail. Something like:

```
-- does something with the wrapped callback, maybe emit a log message or whatever
takesACallback :: (a -> IO (Either e r)) -> a -> IO (Either e r)
```

What if we want to define a version of `takesACallback` for functions `a -> IO r` that *never fail*? Getting into and out of the `Either` is a hassle, and incurs in an spurious pattern-match when getting the value out.

Using `Void` we can start by turning the `a -> IO r` into a `a -> IO (Either Void r)`, pass it into `takesACallback`, and then remove the "fake" error branch on the Either using the [`absurd :: Void -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html) function.

```
takesACallback':: (a -> IO r) -> a -> IO r
takesACallback' callback = fmap (either absurd id) 
                         . takesACallback (fmap Right . callback)
```

[Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conceit-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Conceit.html#v:_runConceit)'s an example of this trick on Hackage.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps! Can't upvote, but accepted.

Comment: @Anton3 Another way of saying that a producer doesn't stop is to leave the return type polymorphic (it can be of any type, because it is never actually returned).

Comment: Thats simply because a polymorphic (independent) return type is isomorphic to Void.